# Customise an array element/fragment of a Symfony form only

Tags: php, html, symfony, symfony-forms, php-5.6

I am attempting to customise the markup of a form element in my Symfony form, however I am having difficulty targeting this element alone. I have read [this section](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-an-individual-field) in the SF cookbook - but I am having difficulty applying it to my situation.

The `form_row` block that I have extended does what I want it to do, however this applies to all `form_row`s called in that template - how can I apply it to `sizes` (which is an array) **only**?

view.html.twig:

```
{% form_theme form 'CRMPiccoProductBundle:CourseGuideRow:fields.html.twig' %}

{{ form_row(form.name) }}
{% for size in form.sizes %}
   {{ form_row(size) }}
{% endfor %}
```

fields.html.twig:

```
{% block form_row %}
    <td style="width: 75px; border-right: 2px solid #000000;">
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
    </td>
{% endblock %}
```

My form is called `crmpicco_course_guide_row`:

```
/**
 * @return string name
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'crmpicco_course_guide_row';
}
```

This results in this markup:

```
    <td style="width: 75px; border-right: 2px solid #000000;">
    <input type="text" class=" form-control" 
required="required" name="crmpicco_course_guide_row[sizes][0]" 
id="crmpicco_course_guide_row_sizes_0">
    </td>
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-an-individual-field

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to apply your form theme only to the "sizes" child forms.

```
{% form_theme form.sizes 'CRMPiccoProductBundle:CourseGuideRow:fields.html.twig' %}
```